# Trouble passing Rails Data into a JavaScript Function on mouse over..? Failed attempt:

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, haml

I want to pass data in rails to a javascript function.

The end goal is to display this data at a specific ID

Here is my current broken attempt:

```
    - if @scopes_in_common.any?
  .compare-box
    - @scopes_in_common[0..2].each_with_index do |scope, index|
      - v_score = instance_variable_get("@#{snake_case(scope.name)}_comparison").v_score.gsub("%", "").to_i
      - (index+1).odd? ? direction = "left" : direction = "right"
      .compare-hex{class: "#{comparison_color(v_score)}-hex"}
        .v_score{class: "#{comparison_color(v_score)}-inner"}
          %a.compare-text{:onmouseover => "showVscore(scope.name)"}
            = v_score

  #VscoreDisplay

:javascript
   function showVscore(scope){
    var Vs = document.getElementById('#VscoreDisplay');
    console.log('SCOPE.NAME', scope);
    Vs.innerHTML = Vs.innerHTML + scope;
  }
```

New to rails. Most of my experience has been in angular, which seems to make this much easier..

Currently, I get "scope is not defined". However, if I set scope.name on a bootstrap tooltip, I can get it to display over that div associated with the tooltip.

But, I want to hover over ".compare-text", which is displaying a score for a specific category, then I want to have the name of that category "scope.name" appear below, within: "#VscoreDisplay".

Or, to append the name related to .compare-text to #VscoreDisplay.

Comment: Can you explain what is currently happening and what is the expected outcome? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Yes. Currently, I get "scope is not defined". However, if I set scope.name on a bootstrap tooltip, I can get it to display over that div associated with the tooltip.

Comment: But, I want to hover over ".compare-text", which is displaying a score for a specific category, then I want to have the name of that category "scope.name"  appear below,  within: "#VscoreDisplay".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error:

> scope is not defined

so you need to *check for the line which is passing scope as argument to the JS function*

```
%a.compare-text{:onmouseover => "showVscore(scope.name)"}
```

if you look at this line, ***you are passing a string to the function, not the name attribute of scope object***.

Fix:

Looking at your code i think you are using Haml so you could fix it by:

```
%a.compare-text{:onmouseover => "showVscore(#{scope.name})"}
```

Comment: Awesome. Syntax was a bit off. but, this makes sense: %a.compare-text{:onmouseover => "showVscore('#{scope.name}')"}

Comment: @stanleytd why do you need to convert name attribute to a string? Isn't it's already a string?

Comment: It was erroring out. I believe it was saying the specific category was not defined, so It was not passing scope, it was attempting to pass in the name for the specific category, instead.   I imagine this has to do with how the instance variable is being passed in rails.